# jQuery animation - not animating correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm a little perplexed, and can't seem to pull together the requisite google fu to track this down. I have a label with a class of `answer__get-the-answer`. When the user clicks the label, a div is supposed to animate down, displaying the answer

```
$('.answer__get-the-answer').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var par = $(this).parent();

    if ( !par.hasClass('selected') ) {
        par
            .addClass('selected')
            .find('.answer__inside')
                .slideDown(500);
    }
});
```

If I select an answer via jQuery in console & execute slideDown, it animates. If I wrap the slideDown in a setTimeout function with a 1ms delay, slideDown animates. But when I execute this code, it doesn't animate. What could cause this?

Comment: The DOM is not [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) yet.

Comment: If accurate, that would prevent the event handler from being assigned (and executing).

Comment: Incidentally, you *could* do the animation entirely using CSS3.

Comment: Gotta support IE8, and the approved list of 3rd party tools doesn't include polyfills (but oddly includes Modernizr). Figure that one out ..

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why this wouldn't work. But I made this, I hope it does what you want.

HTML:

```
<div class="question"> <a class="getanswer">Show me the answer!</a>
    <div class="answer" style="display:none">Pi... The solution to everything.</div>
</div>
```

JS / jQuery:

```
$('.getanswer').on('click', function () {
    var answer = $(this).parent().find(".answer");
    if(!answer.hasClass("selected")){
        answer.slideDown(500);
        answer.addClass("selected");
    }
});
```

This works, I tested it.

I think the problem is that par isn't the parent of `.answer__get-the-answer`. If you could post the HTML too, I can try to figure out the problem.

For so far, I made this Fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWLeb/)

Comment: it's basically the same code that I'm using - other than your 'selected' class is on the wrong element. I know, in a vacuum, that the code I have *should* work. I just can't for the life of me figure out why. I haven't delved too deeply into the animate API, but I was hoping there was some obscure property or setting or something that was off.